# How to display featured images for all posts with certain taxonomy label?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-thumbnails

I have created a post taxonomy in functions.php called 'leadership' and then tagged posts with three different labels.  I have a team page on which I want to place three links (each slugged to a label in the taxonomy).

- Corporate
- Sales
- Support

So that when the above word is clicked, the featured image for each post with that label becomes visible on the page.

So there's three basic elements (I think):

1. Calling all the post data for the specified taxonomic label
2. Generating a link that calls the featured images for those posts
3. Having the content appear/disappear based on which link is clicked

*While I've done #2 and #3 individually before, my head is swimming trying to figure out how to merge all the elements together.*

Can someone give me some pointers, beyond the codex which I've read thru already?  And maybe even some sample code - especially for #1 and #2?

**And the dream...** I'd love to implement it as two shortcodes - one for the link and one for the display - so that I can reuse it in other areas of the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something quite rough that needs improvement but can give you a starting point, if I've understood your needs: use `[dr]` as shortcode marker where you want

```
function my_dream_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
  ob_start(); ?>
  <ul>
    <li class="button" onClick="get_data('corporate')">Corporate</li>
    <li class="button" onClick="get_data('sales')">Sales</li>
    <li class="button" onClick="get_data('support')">Support</li>
  </ul>
<div class="my_plugin_result"></div>
<style>
  li.button{
   list-style:none;
   padding:4px 10px; 
   background-color:cadetblue;
   margin:10px;
   float:left;
   min-width: 160px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  .my_plugin_result figure{
   float:left;
   padding:4px;
   background:#ccc;
}
</style>
<script>
  var myPluginAjaxUrl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
  function get_data(term) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: myPluginAjaxUrl,
      data: {
        action: 'get_data_for_my_shortcode',
        term: term
      }
    }).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      jQuery(".my_plugin_result").html(response);
    });
  }
</script>

<?php
 return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("dr", "my_dream_shortcode");

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data_for_my_shortcode', 'get_data_for_my_shortcode');
//add_action('wp_ajax_get_data_for_my_shortcode', 'get_data_for_my_shortcode');
function get_data_for_my_shortcode(){
  global $wpdb;
  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'leadership',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $_REQUEST['term']
      )
    )
 );
  $response="";
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  while($query->have_posts() ):
    if($query->have_posts() ):
      $query->the_post();
      $response.='<figure><img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'medium').'"/></figure>';
    endif;
  endwhile;
  echo $response;
  die();
}
```

Thanks to  [@bulldog](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35991/bulldog) edited code to work effectively in front-end

Comment: That is SUPER helpful!!  Thank you, @Andrea-Somovigo

Comment: One tweak I want to make and can't quite figure out the right code for...  
I'd like to pass the slug parameter in the shortcode to then display only that link.  
`<li class="button" onClick="get_data($atts)">Show Pics</li>`  
was my attempt, but it doesn't work.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: get_data is a javascript function, if you want to pass a php variable you've to wrap it with <?php ?>

Comment: I've tweaked code and love the end result.  THANK YOU!  

I split out the results into a separate shortcode so I could experiment with different page placements.

Comment: `function mydream_output(){ 
 ob_start(); ?>
 <div style="width:auto;max-width:21em;text-align: center;padding: 1em;"><h3 style="margin-top:2.5em 0 0.5em;">Title</h3><div class="my_plugin_result"></div></div>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("dr_output", "mydream_output");`

Comment: And I'm wondering if there's a way to make the `Title` text display the selected taxonomy term label?

Comment: And @Andrea if I can plead a final question...  Right now I'm displaying results using flexbox.  I'm debating about using a modal window instead, but wondering if it's possible to display these results using WP's add_thickbox() since I don't have a href for the button.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, **the above code will display when logged in**, but not for users logged out.

**If you want site visitors to see output**, then you need to add:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data_for_my_shortcode', 'get_data_for_my_shortcode');
```

It took me a while to troubleshoot this issue.  [Thank you WP Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)